# Why is all my content disappearing when I turn on client validation in ASP.NET MVC 2 RC2?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, client-side

I am using the following partial to render the editor for the Create and Edit pages:

**PersonEditor.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyProj.ViewModels.PersonEditorViewModel>" %>

<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript" />

<%  Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<%  using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
%>
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Edit was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
        <%= Html.EditorForModel()%>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
<%
    }
%>
```

I believe I have followed the instructions correctly on [Scott Gu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) (see "Enabling Client-Side Validation"), but when I load this page in a browser, the entire editor form vanishes. If I remove the two scripts and `Html.EnableClientValidation()`, everything is back to normal again (except, of course, there is no client-side validation).

I have tried putting the script tags in the master page, but that made no difference.

Any ideas how I might be able to fix this?

**Update**

If I put the two `script` tags in Site.Master instead of the partial, *everything* disappears. It basically makes my app completely invisible. No errors, though. It just loads a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script tags are:

1. Different than what is in the blog post you reference, and
2. [Incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work).

They should be:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much!